# How to get the type of Field present in a PDF Form using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

How to get the type of Field present in a PDF Form using PDFBOX. I mean if Radio button and check button is present in a PDF form it should  return me Radio button or check button 
but use getFieldType() method I'm able to returns only "Txt" for Text box and for Radio / Checkbox it return -  "Btn"

```
 PDDocument fdeb = null;

fdeb = PDDocument.load("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Sample.pdf");
PDAcroForm form = fdeb.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
List  FieldTy = form.getFields();
        PDField pdfFields;
for (int i = 0; i < FieldTy.size(); i++) 
  { 
  pdfFields = (PDField) FieldTy.get(i); 
  String fieldNameTyope = pdfFields.getFieldType(); 
      System.out.println(fieldNameTyope);
      }
```

But i need to distinguish wat kind of button is that whether  radio or check box or its a button 
Can any one help me out Please 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will help you

```
      if(pdfFields instanceof PDCheckbox){
            type="CheckBox";
        }else if(pdfFields instanceof PDRadioCollection){
            type="Radio";
        }
```

Comment: Thanks SAN3 for u r quick response !!